# Utorrent won't load my torrent

Tags: bittorrent

I was attempting to torrent a rom for an emulator when I went to sleep, when I woke up the rom hadn't gotten anywhere so I killed that torrent and found a new one. The new one started downloading just fine but when I shut down the computer to allow my computer to rest for a moment and brought it back up Utorrent would no longer open the .torrent, I attempted to remove the torrent and restart it but Utorrent gave me this message "The torrent you are trying to add is already in the list of torrents. Do you want to load the trackers from it?" And whether I hit yes or no it still does nothing.

Note: I know the tag is wrong but there is apparently not a Utorrent tag as of this moment and I can't make one.

Comment: I suppose you can have a screenshot. http://i219.photobucket.com/albums/cc257/Selonianth/Untitled_zpsda595eaf.png

Not that I see how it'll help. And I posted it here because I can't think of a different place to put it. Plus, there is a bittorrent tag. If this isn't the right place go ahead and move it.

Comment: *blinks* Yes actually, why it wasn't showing up when I googled the problem I don't know.